# Should I italicize the name of a paper when referring to it in an email?

Tags: journals

When referring to a journal paper in an email, I'm not sure whether to italicize the name of the paper or to put it in quotation marks.  The paper is 30 pages long.

Since it's an email, are there no real hard rules to follow and so I can leave the title of the paper not italicized or put in quotation marks?

Thanks,

Comment: IMO, plaintext is preferable to HTML, so I favour quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Trivia like whether you italicize the name doesn't matter. What *does* matter is that you include a link to either the paper itself or a page presenting it (e.g. ACM digital library, IEEE express page etc.)

That you can do either with a proper link of the paper's name if you're writing HTML email, or if you write plain text email - which a civilized person should do IMO - use a markdown-like link, i.e.:

```
Hello Professor X,

I am learning a lot from reading "On the frobincation of bars"[1]. Thank you
for recommending it to me.

Sincerely,
user78644

 [1]: http://some.place.here.ac/page/for/the/paper.html
```

Comment: "Hello Professor Xavier,". If you'll be writing a formal email, you might as well write the man's full name. :p

Answer (score 0):

In questions like this, always think, what is important for your reader.

- Unlike journal papers, which are read and re-read by many people, email is usually read by one person one time only. Therefore, the primary goal is to pass the information through smoothly and reliably. Compared to a journal paper, **typographical style matters less** in email. Also, advanced typography is usually based on html, which can be cut down to basic plaintext by many email readers.
- There are **no expectations** for email presentation style. The best you can do it to be consistent within a document. If you cite many papers in your email, it is worth unifying the style for all references. If you cite just one paper, you can choose any citation style which suits you. You can match an existing style (with italics), or you can use your own (with quotes) if you like it better.
- Many readers even don't want to read the paper title; they actually need a **unique reference** to where the content can be found. In many journals, the titles are omitted in bibliography styles, and only author names and years of publication are kept. In email, you can be even more creative and replace it with doi references if you think that is what your reader needs.